Is it dangerous to have no cover on a fluorescent tube (bathroom light)?
I have a bathroom light above my sink with two fluorescent tubes. The acrylic cover that slots into the fixture is "drooping", leaving a small gap from which the light escapes. I've had this issue for a long while now, because I haven't been able to find a suitable replacement.
Is there a possible health hazard to not have the tube adequately covered?
Thank you in advance.

Hey downvoter! Don't be coy! Please let our new member know why you think this question isn't good.

The cover is mainly to soften the glare of the bare light.  It does add some protection to the light tubes from being hit by something.

There is probably some increased risk of electrical shock, due to water being able to condense directly on the tube and it's terminals mire easily. Minor if so.
There is some increase in  risk of glass breakage; the glass in fluorescent tubes is very thin and the shade does provided physical protection as well as it's main purpose of light diffusion
If you have kids in the house I'd suggest looking for ways to fix this.  If it's only yourself... well, I've been ignoring mine for 15 years now, but replacing them with LED fixtures remains on the pending project list.

Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by shock exactly? As in, accidentally hitting the tube?
The gap in the cover is too small to fit anything in through, so I don't think the tube would be easily broken. But I am a bit worried about the harsh light or possible UV radiation coming out of the gap.

Physical discomfort from glare is the only concern. Historically, many lower budget commercial installations simply use bare tubes where there isn't any significant risk of impact.

I would think some tape might cure any problem here.  But without a photo, it's impossible to say!

I was assuming a larger gap than tape would easily cover, but...
